# How to add circle points for multiline chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In this example (jsfiddle.net/vinhnguyenle/LG8Qe/2/), how can I add circle points for 2 line charts?

Answer (score 2):

Add this at the bottom of the script:

```
svg.selectAll("circle.line2")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("fill", "blue")
        .attr("cx", valueline2.x())
        .attr("cy", valueline2.y())
        .attr("r", 4.5);
```